# can too many validation rules cause a performance issue with large data - Apex CPU Time?

Tags: apex, validation-rule, update, performance, cpulimit

I have a bulk update process which effects updates records in more than one salesforce objects like - Account, Contact, Contract , Opportunity and Oppt Line Item.

This bulk process does not update hundreds of records. But, yes - a lot of code is being executed and I get Apex CPU time limit exceeded error when there are more records being processed.

When my bulk process is run : all the triggers , process builders, workflows and validation rules get executed.

I am trying to understand how are validation rules executed - like does each validation rule run each time a save is done?

Does this effect the Apex CPU Time? 
If yes, I would like to deactivate some of the validation rules (over all - I have around 30 of them) which I don't need during this bulk process.

Comment: They do, but they're probably a small percentage of the CPU time when compared with triggers/flows/etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apex Triggers, Flows, and Process Builder consume CPU limits, but validation rules, workflow rules, matching rules, duplicate rules, assignment rules, escalation rules all do *not* count towards the CPU limit. However, there is still also a hard limit of 600,000 ms (10 minutes) for every transaction. If you're running in to CPU limits, it is most likely a combination of Triggers and Processes. Yes, validation rules are run at least once per DML operation, as noted in [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm). Having a ton of Validation Rules does not impact the governor limit directly. It's hard to verify certain scenarios, like if a trigger calls a DML operation, etc, but it's been my experience that only Apex Triggers can even trigger (no pun intended) a CPU governor limit error.

Comment: I was referring to this link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339361&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1 and it is mentioned that time spent evaluating the formula validation rules is considered. This confuses me.

Comment: @user2598808 Sounds erroneous. As far as I'm aware, validation rules don't use any CPU time.